# What is more efficient for printing logs with log4j String or StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, log4j, stringbuilder

Guys I have lot of logs printing in my small java utility,so just thought of this question, if its a very big system and efficiency matters, and if we have lot of logs generated (using log4j) which is the better object to hold the logging messages
String or StringBuilder.

Comment: Efficient how?  Are you looking for better throughput or more economical memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. Are you planning to manipulate the strings such as concatenating them together? If so, StringBuilder would be better. If not, String would be better.

Answer (score 5):

If your choice is between

```
logger.Debug(string1 + string2);
```

and

```
logger.Debug(new StringBuilder(string1).append(string2).toString());
```

Then there is no difference

But if there are lots of checks and constructs like `logString += <something>` then using a `StringBuilder` is better.

Note that the biggest efficiency issue with log4j comes from evaluating expressions without checking for log level. You *always* need

```
if (logger.isDebug())
    logger.Debug(..));
```

Lot of CPU cycles have been wasted concatenating strings and evaluating other expressions whose results will soon be discarded because logger is set to a higher level.

Answer (score 4):

If you're really logging that much stuff, I would imagine the volume of stuff you're outputting to, say, a file, makes more difference than which in-memory object you pick.

Which is to say: you're maybe logging too much?

That said, StringBuilder appending will be more efficient than just String appending, assuming you keep adding to a log message's contents, but I'd be very surprised if it made any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 2):

Most logging systems supply some kind if mechanism to insert parameters (eg. `log.Debug("foo = {}", getFooValue()`). This is the preferred and most efficient way.

Some people will suggest to use a stringbuilder like this: `stringBuilder.append(foo).append(bar).toString()`, however this is not more efficient than `"foo" + "bar"`.

I cannot find a online source for it now, but I remember that if you look at the bytecode of those two code fragments, it will be identical.

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is your concern, your logs should be minimal required. Logs can prove to be a major overhead in your system it you are logging too much. and when you do thing too much performance difference between string and stringBuffer will fade.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it you could pass it as a String you are better off because you save the call to `toString` on the `StringBuilder`.

However, if you really want to improve efficiency you might consider passing something like a String Supplier. This would allow you to check the logging level prior to producing the log message in the cases where this is not simply a String.

Answer (score 0):

String concatination can be very expensive. StringBuilder takes care of part of this.  However a much better approach is to make use of String.format.  This method take a pattern String and a variable number of arguments which are null safe converted to Strings for substitution.